# Problema al ejecutar un archivo HTML

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, web

Cree una web sencilla con HTML, JavaScript y Bootstrap, cuando la ejecuto con Vscode con la extensión de **Live Server**, la aplicación funciona perfectamente, pero cuando ejecuto sólo el archivo html (Como debería ser), carga la parte HTML normal , más no carga la parte HTML que usa JavaScript.

No sé si sea necesario mostrar el código, pues como les explico si funciona bien cuando lo ejecuto con Live Server de Vscode, aunque les dejo una imagen de los archivos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si esto tenga que ver pero tengo las etiquetas script así:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-p34f1UUtsS3wqzfto5wAAmdvj+osOnFyQFpp4Ua3gs/ZVWx6oOypYoCJhGGScy+8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="codigo.js" type="module"></script>
```

A la de `codigo.js` le puse el `type="module"`, porque si no no se conectaba con la de `base_de_datos_curso.js`.

**Error de consola**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para que tu código funcione siempre necesitas tener un servidor corriendo puede ser el que te provee Live server, uno en node.js o alguno de Python inclusive, esto es necesario para poder servir las demás dependencias de tu index.html, como lo son los archivos `,js` ya que cuando lo abres directamente en el navegador se utiliza el protocolo file y este no soporta cargar dependencias.

Comment: Cuando abre el fichero HTML directamente, ¿qué errores ves en la consola del navegador?

Comment: Lo acabo de poner

Comment: Como dijo @Daniel necesitas un servidor que sirva los demas archivos, no verás nada al abrir el archivo de la forma `C:/users/dir/index.html` deberás tener un servidor `localhost/dir/index.html`

Comment: Te recomiendo que pruebes a instalar Laragon (si usas windows), es muy sencillo de configurar e incluso de activar virtualhost; pues tal y como te comentan arriba, para que tu html cargue correctamente dependencias debes ejecutarlo en un servidor (apache, nginx...)